# How to insert animate in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to expand a `<div>` element of my page to whole screen width and height.
Now I'm able todo this, but I also want to show an animation when the `<div>` enlarges to screen size.

This is the code that I have used to animate it:

```
$htmlEditorContainer.animate({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
 },
 {
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function () {
    }
 });
```

But with this code, the `<div>` shows directly at 100% screen size.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you can try this modification

```
$("#div").animate({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height()
        },
        1000,//duration
        'linear',//easing
        animationComplete //complete function
);

function animationComplete() {
    alert("Animation Completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code seems almost correct (the `$htmlEditorContainer` looks quirky). So maybe there's something wrong with your HTML. Here's a working snippet:

```js
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#htmlEditorContainer" ).animate({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function () {
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="htmlEditorContainer" style="position: absolute; top:50px; left: 10px; background-color:yellow;">HTMLEditorContainer</div>
```